# Android:text from string array

Tags: android, arrays, string, text, textview

Is it possible to set text of textview in xml from string array? (like android:text="@string/title[3]" if I want to set the third item) Or I have to do it programatically?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not possible. `textview.setText(title[3])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot access in layout xml file.

But you can do it in java

```
    String[] some_array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.your_string_array);
textView.setText(some_array[5]);
```